# Can we merge geoip and geo-location?

Tags: support, retag-request

[image]

They cover the same topics. I would prefer `geo-location` to be the winning tag, as this would keep things consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I have completed moving all questions to "geolocation" tag.

It would not let me create the "geo-location" because it thought it already existed with "geolocation".